# SQL Server 2017 Replication - Subscriber/Publisher Version Compatibility

Tags: sql, replication, compatibility, subscriber, sql-server-2017

Is it possible to have a SQL Server 2017 subscriber to a SQL Server 2012 publication (distributor running SQL Server 2016) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. Documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/upgrade-replicated-databases).

> Subscriber version depends on the type of publication:
>
> - A Subscriber to a transactional publication can be any version within two versions of the Publisher version. For example: a SQL
>     Server 2012 Publisher can have SQL Server 2014 and SQL Server 2016
>     Subscribers; and a SQL Server 2016 Publisher can have SQL Server 2014
>     and SQL Server 2012 Subscribers.
> - A Subscriber to a merge publication can be any version less than or equal to the Publisher version.